# python -Roman numeral converter "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, typeerror, roman-numerals

I am still pretty new to coding and I've been trying to complete this challenge a friend set me. I have to convert a list of numbers from the user to their roman numerals. I however get a "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" with my second function that I use.

```
def romanizer(n, arr):

    output = []

    for i in range(n):
        individual = arr.pop(0)
        x = convert(individual)
        output.append(x)

    print output

def convert(num):

    roman_table = { 1000: 'M', 900: 'CM', 500: 'D',
                    400: 'CD' , 100: 'C', 90: 'XC',
                    50: 'L', 40: 'XL', 10: 'X', 
                    9: 'IX', 5: 'V', 4: 'IV',
                    1: 'I'}  

    roman = ''
    while num > 0:
        for number, numeral in roman_table: # This is where the error sends me
            while num >= number:
                roman += numeral
                num -= number 

    return roman

units = int(raw_input("How many numbers must be converted? "))
numbers = raw_input("Which numbers? ")
converted = list(map(int, numbers.split()))

print units
print numbers

romanizer(units, converted)
```

I get the following error after I do the following input:

```
How many numbers must be converted? 2
Which numbers? 111 506
2
111 506

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "romanizer.py", line 37, in <module>
    romanizer(units, converted)
  File "romanizer.py", line 9, in romanizer
    x = convert(individual)
  File "romanizer.py", line 24, in convert
    for number, numeral in roman_table:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Could someone here maybe help me if at all possible? I'm not sure why I get the error because it's supposed to use the number to iterate through my dictionary for the conditions I've set. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please include the *full traceback* of the error, as well as the inputs you gave that led to the error and the output you expected instead.

Comment: You probably wanted to use `for number, numeral in roman_table.items():` there, you can't split the numeric keys into two different values.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I've actually asked a question here, still figuring out how to do it...

Comment: I tried using 'for number, numeral in roman_table.items():' there but it just gives a long output of roman I's

Comment: Well, that's a different issue, you are not sorting your values there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping over a dictionary yields *only the keys*, but you are trying to assign each key to two variables:

```
for number, numeral in roman_table:
```

Your keys are integers, so the loop tries to do this:

```
>>> number, numeral = 1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

giving you the exception.

Loop over `roman_table.items()` instead:

```
for number, numeral in roman_table.items():
```

However, dictionaries are *unordered*. You really want to start with the *big* roman numerals first, not with just any, so *sort* your items:

```
for number, numeral in sorted(roman_table.items(), reverse=True):
```

Sorting has a cost too; you'd probably want to list your table as a sequence, not a dictionary, so you can avoid the sorting:

```
roman_table = [
    (1000, 'M'), (900, 'CM'), (500, 'D'), (400, 'CD'), (100, 'C'),
    (90, 'XC'), (50, 'L'), (40, 'XL'), (10, 'X'), (9, 'IX'), (5, 'V'),
    (4, 'IV'), (1, 'I')
]

for number, numeral in roman_table:
```

The table is now a list of tuples, so there is no need to use `.items()` anymore either.

With a reverse-sorted table, you get correct output:

```
>>> convert(111)
'CXI'
>>> convert(506)
'DVI'
>>> convert(999)
'CMXCIX'
```

Comment: I tried doing that now but all I get is a list roman I's like this: 'How many numbers must be converted? 2' 'Which numbers? 11 51' '['IIIIIIIIIII', 'IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII']'
I assume then there must be some error in my logic...

Comment: @C.Viljoen: there is, and there was in mine too. Reverse the sort.